# Terminal in Cat Mode says -s: command not found

Tags: command-line, mac, cat

awhile ago i was installing something and doing some stuff with terminal, and i think i messed it up. on the terminal app it says "Terminal - cat - 80x24" then inside terminal it says:

```
Last login: Wed Jan 1 14:05:47 on ttys000

-bash: [[-s: command not found
```

is there a way to reinstate my terminal to original settings? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that your login shell (`-bash`) had a problem parsing its init file (have you edited `~/.bashrc` or equivalent recently?), and failed where you had "`[[-s`" (you probably wanted "`[[ -s`", with a space between "`[[`" and "`-s`").

You can find it via

> egrep '\[\[-s' .bashrc   .bash_profile .bash_login
>   /etc/profile/etc/bash.bashrc /etc/environment

Not all of those files will exist, but, if they do, check them.